# How can I read the excel file(xslx) which is in the Sharepoint server directly from informatica Powercenter?

Tags: unix, informatica-powercenter

I Have a Excel file(xlsl) with multiple worksheets in Sharepoint server which I should read in informatica and load the data into different tables.
Informatica is hosted on unix server

Currently I am thinking of the below work around but I have challenges here:
1.Copying the excel file into unix.(Once i copy the file from sharepoint server to unix using the "curl" command, the format of the file is getting changed to html. I can I retain the original excel format ,I can't install any excel utility on our server)

2.Convert them into multiple CSV files using some script (How can I do this, As I mentioned earlier I don't have any utilities like xls2csv, unoconv )

3.And read the CSV file and load them into tables.

Please let me know if there is any better approach than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using wget to download the excel file (or set of files) from the sharepoint to Informatica file server location. It will allow you to specify the directory and target file name as well.